# How to draw randomly-placed rectangles in Haskell's SDL2 bindings?

Tags: haskell, sdl, monads

I'm trying to draw randomly-positioned rectangles in SDL2 using Haskell. The IO monad is really driving me insane and I can't get it to work.  I have the boilerplate SDL2 code ready to go and a custom datatype for the `RectangleObject`, and all I want to do is randomly generate the rectangles in the `main` function, then draw them inside the `appLoop` function.

I get the error:

```
BadRandomRectangles.hs:17:61-85: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: [RectangleObject]
                  with actual type: IO [RectangleObject]
    • In the fourth argument of ‘GameState’, namely
        ‘(createRandomRectangles 10)’
      In the expression:
        GameState
          (V2 10 10) (V2 40 40) (V2 1 1) (createRandomRectangles 10)
      In an equation for ‘gameState’:
          gameState
            = GameState
                (V2 10 10) (V2 40 40) (V2 1 1) (createRandomRectangles 10)
   |
17 |   let gameState = GameState (V2 10 10) (V2 40 40) (V2 1 1) (createRandomRectangles 10) in
   |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import SDL
import System.Random
import Control.Monad (unless, replicateM)
import Foreign.C.Types (CInt)

data RectangleObject = RectangleObject { rectPosn :: V2 CInt, rectDim :: V2 CInt };

data GameState = GameState { posn :: V2 CInt, dim :: V2 CInt, vel :: V2 CInt, objects :: [RectangleObject] };

main :: IO ()
main = do
  initializeAll
  window <- createWindow "Rectangles" (defaultWindow { windowInitialSize = V2 640 480 })
  renderer <- createRenderer window (-1) defaultRenderer
  let gameState = GameState (V2 10 10) (V2 40 40) (V2 1 1) (createRandomRectangles 10) in
    appLoop renderer gameState
  destroyRenderer renderer
  destroyWindow window
  quit

appLoop :: Renderer -> GameState -> IO ()
appLoop renderer gameState = do
  events <- pollEvents

  clear renderer
  rendererDrawColor renderer $= V4 0 0 0 255

  -- Get the RectangleObjects from the game state and draw them
  let objs = objects gameState
  mapM_ (\(RectangleObject posn dim) -> fillRect renderer (Just $ Rectangle (P $ posn) dim)) objs

  -- Fill a rectangle of size 1280x720 with black color
  fillRect renderer (Just $ Rectangle (P $ V2 0 0) (V2 1280 720))
  rendererDrawColor renderer $= V4 255 0 0 255

  fillRect renderer (Just $ Rectangle (P $ posn gameState) (dim gameState))
  present renderer
  SDL.delay 16
  unless qPressed (appLoop renderer (updateGameState vGameState))

updateGameState :: GameState -> GameState
updateGameState (GameState posn dim vel objs) =
  GameState (posn + vel) dim vel objs

createRandomRectangles :: Int -> IO [RectangleObject]
createRandomRectangles n = replicateM n generateRandomRectangle

generateRandomRectangle :: IO RectangleObject
generateRandomRectangle = do
  x <- randomRIO (1, 10)
  y <- randomRIO (1, 10)
  w <- randomRIO (1, 10)
  h <- randomRIO (1, 10)
  return $ RectangleObject (V2 x y) (V2 w h)
```

Comment: So what's the issue? Does it not compile -> add the error message. Does it behave differently from what you expect -> add both expected and actual behavior.

Comment: @TheSinisterStone, I added the (main) error message your question.  If this wasn't the problem you were having, you can either edit the question to explain your problem better, or you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that, in this code:

```
let gameState = GameState (V2 10 10) (V2 40 40) (V2 1 1) (createRandomRectangles 10) in
  appLoop renderer gameState
```

the expression `createRandomRectangles 10` is of type `IO [RectangleObject]`, but the fourth field in your `GameState` object is a pure `[RectangleObject]`.

Rewrite this as:

```
rects <- createRandomRectangles 10
let gameState = GameState (V2 10 10) (V2 40 40) (V2 1 1) rects in
  appLoop renderer gameState
```

and your `main` function should type check.

There were still a couple of undefined variables in your code (`qPressed` and `vGameState`) and some logic errors in your renderer (e.g., you were drawing the random rectangles and then erasing them by drawing over them with a black rectangle).  Also, the random rectangles were so small, they just showed up as little blips in the top left corner.

After making a couple adjustments, the following code seemed to work and even looked "game-like".  Good luck!

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import SDL
import System.Random
import Control.Monad (unless, replicateM)
import Foreign.C.Types (CInt)

data RectangleObject = RectangleObject { rectPosn :: V2 CInt, rectDim :: V2 CInt };

data GameState = GameState { posn :: V2 CInt, dim :: V2 CInt, vel :: V2 CInt, objects :: [RectangleObject] };

main :: IO ()
main = do
  initializeAll
  window <- createWindow "Rectangles" (defaultWindow { windowInitialSize = V2 640 480 })
  renderer <- createRenderer window (-1) defaultRenderer
  rects <- createRandomRectangles 10
  let gameState = GameState (V2 10 10) (V2 40 40) (V2 1 1) rects in
    appLoop renderer gameState
  destroyRenderer renderer
  destroyWindow window
  quit

appLoop :: Renderer -> GameState -> IO ()
appLoop renderer gameState = do
  events <- pollEvents

  clear renderer

  -- Fill a rectangle of size 1280x720 with black color
  rendererDrawColor renderer $= V4 0 0 0 255
  fillRect renderer (Just $ Rectangle (P $ V2 0 0) (V2 1280 720))

  -- Get the RectangleObjects from the game state and draw them in green
  let objs = objects gameState
  rendererDrawColor renderer $= V4 255 255 0 255
  mapM_ (\(RectangleObject posn dim) -> fillRect renderer (Just $ Rectangle (P $ posn) dim)) objs

  -- Draw the main game rectangle in red
  rendererDrawColor renderer $= V4 255 0 0 255
  fillRect renderer (Just $ Rectangle (P $ posn gameState) (dim gameState))

  present renderer
  SDL.delay 16

  -- unless qPressed (appLoop renderer (updateGameState vGameState))
  appLoop renderer (updateGameState gameState)

updateGameState :: GameState -> GameState
updateGameState (GameState posn dim vel objs) =
  GameState (posn + vel) dim vel objs

createRandomRectangles :: Int -> IO [RectangleObject]
createRandomRectangles n = replicateM n generateRandomRectangle

generateRandomRectangle :: IO RectangleObject
generateRandomRectangle = do
  let scale = 500
  x <- randomRIO (1, scale)
  y <- randomRIO (1, scale)
  w <- randomRIO (1, scale)
  h <- randomRIO (1, scale)
  return $ RectangleObject (V2 x y) (V2 w h)
```